# Travel agent is claiming I have made an online booking but I haven't

Tags: bookings, scams

Today I got call from a Travel Agent and a  mail which shows that I have booked a ticket to fly  to India on 15th and return date 25 August 2017. Travel agent said I have booked the tickets.

However, I have NOT made any such booking.

I told him that I haven't booked any ticket online and that he should cancel it. But the agent wants me to pay for the tickets and said he cannot cancel.

Also I got a call from my bank HSBC asking me not to give my bank statements and bank card pin number  to anyone.

I never gave these things to anyone.

What is going on and how should I proceed? Is the booking real? How can I find the culprit?

Comment: This question is more about dealing with fraud than about travel.

Comment: If you haven't paid there can't have been a booking. Ignore the agent.

Comment: It sounds like you've been a victim of identity theft: somebody has used your bank details to buy stuff in your name. This has nothing to do with travel, since it's purely coincidental that the fraudster booked a hotel rather than, say, buying a laptop. You need to talk to your bank about this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about identity theft and/or bank fraud. The travel aspect is purely coincidental.

Comment: Any travel agent that says they cannot cancel a ticket (assuming it was booked through them) is ***LYING***. Any ticket, even issued ones, can be cancelled unless the flight has already departed. If they’re asking for payment, the ticket has not been issued.

Comment: When *"the bank" called you*, did they ask for any of your bank account numbers, e.g. to "verify" your identity?   This is a common scam: they are not really the bank, and are hoping you will forget that they called you. You give them the numbers expecting them to compare to what they already have, in fact, they are learning the numbers! Now they rip you off.  They caution you not to give out PINs etc. in order to sound legit so you wont realize you've been scammed.  The call from the fake travel agent was a red herring, it was to make you believe the following fake bank call was real.

Answer (score 19):

**This is almost certainly a scam**, so do nothing except keep an eye on your credit card statement in case your card has been compromised.

If you want to set your mind at ease, ask the "travel agent" for the **last name** used in the ticket and your **PNR** aka **trip locator**: this is the 6-letter identifier attached to *every* flight booking ever.  Then call the airline or go to their website and check if you can find it: if you can't, there is no ticket.

If you *do* find a booking, let the airline, your credit card company and the police know ASAP: the scammer will get more than they bargained for if they check in!

Comment: To check with the airline, do it via a phone call, not the website. At least with Air France, some booking refs do not show up when entering the reference on the website, even if they exist. (That's probably all the booking that do not accept changes nor online check in.)

Comment: The last brick-and-mortar travel agency that I used also kept the PNR 6-letter identifier for themselves until the flight had been paid in full. It could be the case that the scam call maker would cite a similar rule when asking for it.

Comment: @DCTLib Even if they do keep the PNR to themselves, they can absolutely cancel the booking. Saying a booking cannot be cancelled is a straight-up lie in all cases.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: A booking can always be cancelled, but sometimes there are fees... or the ticket is simply not reimbursed. Therefore, the scammer could use *that* as an appeal for payment.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I’ve never heard of a travel agent booking through a normal booking system like Amadeus, Sabre, Galileo, etc., having to pay a fee to book or cancel. Airlines and especially travel agents frequently charge a fee to _customers_ for cancelling bookings, but I’ve never seen one being charged in the booking system itself. Since the scammer here is asking for payment for the ticket, there cannot be an issued ticket unless the travel agent has paid out of pocket for the ticket (which seems beyond unlikely), only a booking.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Agree with Janus: commonly, the ticket "hold" placed by the agent is only valid for (eg.) 24 hours, but the hold is free and you only need to pay if you go ahead and "issue".  If you don't issue, the hold is simply cancelled.

Answer (score 18):

No one booked anything. You got a scam call, hope you didn't give them your credit card information. I have no idea how bank statements or PIN code got into this mess.

Comment: If the call from the bank was incoming, or made by the bank to the OP, it could be part of the scam, especially if they had him *verify* details of his bank account...

Answer (score 4):

You should stay cool and double-check your credit card/bank statements in the next few days. If nothing shows up there, then you should be fine.

Every proper travel agency will not allow you to book a ticket online before they have your payment information. So they should not need to call you.

As your bank said, don't ever give your account information to someone you do not know and who called *you*.